# asp.net app slow and not rendering but .txt file works fine?

Tags: asp.net

i have a load balanced set of 2 servers running a .net application that is loading slow and not at all to the point the load balancer is redirecting me and my users to our dr server.

i added a hard coded file to both servers to tell what server is working and not. both pull the txt file and display its contents in no time. however the asp.net pages dont render.

the DB is not sweating and even a plain .aspx page doesnt come up.

any thoughts on trouble shooting this?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a IIS 7 server? If so you could use [failed request tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-70/) to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way for you to load a page from a specific server and skip the load balancer?  You could try logging on to the server and opening a browser to http://localhost/ or something along those lines and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.

- Get rid of the load balancer (i.e. test from behind it).
- Check CPU load. What is the timeout?

Possibly cause:

- Initial first page takes too long (aplication start = page compile). In this case look for a warm load tool (depends on IIS version), basically starting "locally" before first request.... or up the timeout on the redirector.

Could be your app takes 20 secnods to start, but the redirector redirects after 5 ;)

For the current version of IIS... check http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationWarmUp

Comment: hi all,

i tested behind the LB and pages work as they do from the public side. they load slow and or not at all.

the redirection takes over a minute to send to DR so .net pages should load within a couple seconds.

i am using IIS 6

Answer (score 0):

I like the process you are on, keep eliminating possible problems.

Next thing I would check is inside of the asp.net web.config and default web.config and machine.config files.  Look at

1. Which modules and handlers are being loaded / processed by the site.
2. What kind of session state is being used (turned off, in process, state machine or database).

Next try to modify settings of modules / handlers (one at a time to see what is taking so long).

Another option (if you have it) is to attach something like Ants Profiler and let it tell you where all of the time is being spent.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that a plain aspx doesn't load. I assume this is just a blank web form it equivalent? If not, try that.

Can you create a new, entirely separate, default web app on one of the servers and test? This should tell you if there is any issue with the site itself -web.config, handlers, etc that get called before the pages are rendered.

If a plain site doesn't work, you've got some problem within IIS, or ASP.Net components or config. If it does, there us an issue with your web app, and you should probably start adding components from the old site into the new one.

ALSO: when did this start? Do you
have a prior version of your app in source control that you can test? For that matter, does your app work on your test or staging servers?